# Absolute Value Derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let's say I have the function $f(x) = 10|x-2| - x^2 $ and I want to find the derivative. Since I can rewrite $ |x| $ as $\sqrt(x^2) $, can I also rewrite $ |x-2| $ as $ \sqrt{(x-2)^2}$ ?   (sorry for weird formatting Im new here)

Comment: You can come and go between those expressions as much as you want. But in any case, remember that the formulas you get from that only tell you what the derivative is at those points where the argument of the absolute value is not 0. At those other points (like $x=2$ in your example), you can conclude nothing from the formula. The proper way to decide about existence (and eventually value) of derivative at that point is from definition.

Answer (score 0):

Generally we introduce the sign function $\operatorname{sgn(x)}=\dfrac x{|x|}=\pm 1$ for $x\neq 0$ and $\operatorname{sgn}(0)=0$

[ *The value in zero is a convention but we can also choose to let it undefined*. ]

This way we can derivate $f(x)=|x-2|$

$f(x):\begin{cases}x-2 & \text{for } x\ge 2\\ 2-x & \text{for } x\le 2\end{cases}\quad$ thus $\quad f'(x):\begin{cases}+1 & \text{for } x> 2\\ -1 & \text{for } x< 2\end{cases}$

Or similarly $f'(x)=\operatorname{sgn}(x-2)$ for $x\neq 2$

Your remark about using the square root, leads indeed to that same result:

$f(x)=|x-2|=\sqrt{(x-2)^2}$

$f'(x)=\dfrac{\frac 12\times2\times(x-2)}{\sqrt{(x-2)^2}}=\dfrac{x-2}{|x-2|}=\operatorname{sgn}(x-2)\quad$ as defined above for $x\neq 2$.

[ *Again, the derivative in $x=2$ does not exists, in the strict functional sense since there is a discontinuity there, it only exists as a distribution, but this is another subject.* ]

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d|x-2|}{dx}=\frac{|x-2|}{x-2},x \ne 2$$
The derivative does not exist when $x=2$

Answer (score -1):

Absolute Value can be viewed as finding the magnitude, or radius of a vector.
So using Pythagorean Theorem:$|x+y|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for $x+y\in \Bbb R^{2}$. Since your term is in $\Bbb R^{1}$, one of the vector components is necessarily $0$.

Letting $y=0$ and $x=u-2$:

You get $|u-2|=\sqrt{(u-2)^2}$

You can also view the Absolute Value as a piece-wise function $|x-a|=x-a$, for $x>a$ and $|x-a|=a-x$, for $x<a$.

Differentiating:$$\frac{d|x-a|}{dx}=1,x>a$$
and $$\frac{d|x-a|}{dx}=-1, x<a$$

Comment: $|x+y|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$???

Comment: @zipirovich Im just using Pythagorean Theorem what dont you understand? $x$ and $y$ are both vector components/sides of a triangle.

Comment: Are they ($x$ and $y$) numbers or vectors? Because if they are numbers -- as seems to be the case, since you're going to substitute other numbers for them -- then "$x+y$" does **not** mean the vector with components $x$ and $y$. Or an even more simple explanation: since it's okay to substitute numbers for $x$ and $y$ (you did that yourself), what happens if we let $y=1$ and $x=1$?

Comment: It is only ok to substitute in that situation if $x+y\in \Bbb R^{2}$ Since the term in the problem is in $\Bbb R^{1}$ one of the components has to be $0$ and the other one has to be the term.

Comment: @zipirovich I'm suprised that you are hung up on this fact but if it will make it clearer I will edit.